# Spring StringTrimmerEditor nullifying field instead of disallowing

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, model-view-controller, trim

I'm using Spring's `registerCustomEditor` to trim all the leading/trailing space, But I do not want it to executive on specific fields like for instance password field.

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class MyCustomControllerAdvice {

    @InitBinder
    public void setupDefaultInitBinder(WebDataBinder binder) {

        binder.setDisallowedFields("*password");  
        binder.registerCustomEditor(String.class, new StringTrimmerEditor(true)); 


    }
}
```

Now, when I am **POST** with `password=[space][space]MyPassword` , the controller is getting `null` instead of `[space][space]MyPassword`

Comment: That is what you configured. `password` is a field that isn't allowed, hence it won't be bound, hence it will always be `null`.

Comment: I see. Then how can I achieve what I am desiring for ? It doesn't make sense to trim anything user is typing in a password field, but I do want it to trim in other fields like Name where space is more of user experience issue.

Comment: Register a specific editor for the password field not the `StringTrimmerEditor`.

Comment: The problem is how do i exclude the StringTrimmerEditor for password field ? I could include a new one in initBinder for PasswordController, but still the one in ControllerAdvice would get added as well

Comment: or can i exclude ControllerAdvice for some URL patterns ?

Comment: As I stated register [a specific](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/validation/DataBinder.html#registerCustomEditor-java.lang.Class-java.lang.String-java.beans.PropertyEditor-) one for the password field. That will take precedence over the global registered one.

Comment: I added a initBinder in PasswordController.    binder.registerCustomEditor(String.class, new PropertyEditorSupport()); But the one in ControllerAdvice is invoked laters so its overwriting it.

Comment: Trying your solution...

Answer (score 1):

```
@InitBinder   
public void initBinder(WebDataBinder binder) {
    binder.registerCustomEditor(String.class, new StringTrimmerEditor(true));

    PropertyEditorSupport dummyEditor = new PropertyEditorSupport() {

        @Override
        public void setAsText(String text) throws IllegalArgumentException {
            super.setValue(text);
        }

    };

    binder.registerCustomEditor(String.class, "password", dummyEditor);
}
```